# Why <Choice> Node is created while using XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema?

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xsd, xsd.exe

To Create a xml schema from a json, I convert the Json to XML and then use XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema. The resulted Xml Schema contains a choice node. 
Below is the xml genereated from Json

```
<RESPONSE_DATA>
    <ok>true</ok>
    <messages>
        <type>message</type>
        <subtype>file_share</subtype>
        <text>something</text>
        <file>
            <id>IFD</id>
            <created>1468845544</created>
            <timestamp>1468845544</timestamp>           
        </file>
        <user>IJSA</user>
        <upload>true</upload>
        <display_as_bot>false</display_as_bot>
        <username>&lt;@U1J8V9&gt;</username>
        <bot_id />
        <ts>1468845544.000002</ts>
    </messages>
    <messages>
        <user>U1J98V9</user>
        <text>9EK8V9</text>
        <type>message</type>
        <subtype>group_join</subtype>
        <ts>1468472817.000002</ts>
    </messages>
    <has_more>false</has_more>
</RESPONSE_DATA>
```

Below is the xmlschema generated using XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="RESPONSE_DATA">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ok" type="xs:boolean" />
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="messages">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="type" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="subtype" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="text" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="file">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:string" />
                                            <xs:element name="created" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
                                            <xs:element name="timestamp" type="xs:unsignedInt" />                                           
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                                <xs:element name="user" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="upload" type="xs:boolean" />
                                <xs:element name="display_as_bot" type="xs:boolean" />
                                <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" />
                                <xs:element name="bot_id" />
                                <xs:element name="ts" type="xs:decimal" />
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="has_more" type="xs:boolean" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I use TreeNodeCollection to get all nodes of the schema element and use TreeNode.Text to get the name. Treenode.Text for the choice node gives me value as `<Choice>` instead of `choice` and that breaks my code.

Answer (score 0):

Both `messages` elements share 5 common child elements (`type`, `subtype`, `text`, `user`, `ts`), but they're not in the same order.

The resulting schema essentially says 'any of this stuff is valid inside `messages`, but the order isn't important'.